# React table from object with objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got 2 types of json API and i want to display them in table. First one has following structure:

```
data1:[
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Leanne Graham",
              "username": "Bret",
              "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
              "address":"Gwenborough",
              "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
              "website": "hildegard.org",
              "company": "Romaguera-Crona"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Ervin Howell",
              "username": "Antonette",
              "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
              "address": "Wisokyburgh",
              "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
              "website": "anastasia.net",
              "company": "Deckow-Crist"
            }
]
```

Second:

```
data2:[
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Leanne Graham",
            "username": "Bret",
            "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
            "address": {
              "street": "Kulas Light",
              "suite": "Apt. 556",
              "city": "Gwenborough",
              "zipcode": "92998-3874",
              "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
              }
            },
            "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
            "website": "hildegard.org",
            "company": {
              "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
              "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
              "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ervin Howell",
            "username": "Antonette",
            "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
            "address": {
              "street": "Victor Plains",
              "suite": "Suite 879",
              "city": "Wisokyburgh",
              "zipcode": "90566-7771",
              "geo": {
                "lat": "-43.9509",
                "lng": "-34.4618"
              }
            },
          }
        ]
```

My Table component works for first type of data (data1) and creates a table. But obviously for second (data2) type i'm getting error. I tried a lot of things and i can't get access to address and geo fields and can't display them in table.
Table component:

```
export default class Table extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.getHeader = this.getHeader.bind(this);
      this.getRowsData = this.getRowsData.bind(this);
      this.getKeys = this.getKeys.bind(this);
     
    }
      getKeys = function(){
        return Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
      }
      
      getHeader = function(){
        var keys = this.getKeys();
        return keys.map((key, index)=>{
          return <th key={key}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
      }

      getRowsData = function(){
        var items = this.props.data;
        var keys = this.getKeys();
        return items.map((row, index)=>{
          return <tr key={index}><RenderRow key={index} data={row} keys={keys}/></tr>
        })
      }
    
    
    render() {
        console.log('Get keys:', this.getKeys());
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>{this.getHeader()}</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.getRowsData()}
            </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          
        );
    }
}
const RenderRow = (props) =>{
  return props.keys.map((key, index)=>{
    return <td key={props.data[key]}>{props.data[key]}</td>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const uniqueArr = [...data1, ...data2]


const formatData = uniqueArr.map((item) => {
    if(typeof item.address === "object"){
    return {
        ...item,
        address:  item.address.street.concat(", ", item.address.city),
      company: item.company ?  item.company.name : ""
    }
  }
    return item
})
```